# categories and subcategories and products query not working as intended

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all the categories and subcategories and there products using a single query from a categories table which has a parent_id for subcategories and a products table. But I am not getting the exact results. 
I am not sure where I am doing it wrong.

My query uses 5 tables which are :

1. **products** - this table has a `products_id` field and other details
2. **products_description**  - this table holds the `products_name` and `products_id` fields
3. **products_to_categories** - this table contains the products_id linked to `categories_id` fields
4. **categories** - this table contains the `categories_id` and its other fields and `parent_id` field
5. **categories_description** - this table contains `categories_id` and `categories_name` fields.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT  p.products_id, pd.products_name, cd.categories_id AS main_category_id, cd.categories_name ,c.categories_id AS subcategory
 FROM products p
 INNER JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id=p.products_id 
 INNER JOIN products_to_categories p2c ON p2c.products_id=p.products_id 
 INNER JOIN categories c ON p2c.categories_id=c.categories_id 
 INNER JOIN categories_description cd ON cd.categories_id=c.categories_id 
 GROUP BY cd.categories_id
```

Comment: Can you provide samples of data and explain how this doesn't return what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing wrong is the last inner join on clause condition where you have written cd.categories_id=c.categories_id.

You should change it to this cd.categories_id=c.parent_id

So your final query will be :

```
SELECT  p.products_id, pd.products_name, cd.categories_id AS main_category_id, cd.categories_name ,c.categories_id AS subcategory
 FROM products p
 INNER JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id=p.products_id 
 INNER JOIN products_to_categories p2c ON p2c.products_id=p.products_id 
 INNER JOIN categories c ON p2c.categories_id=c.categories_id 
 INNER JOIN categories_description cd ON cd.categories_id=c.parent_id
 GROUP BY cd.categories_id
```